# Testing node app. mocha/chai how to invoke function to test against internal variables

Tags: node.js, chai

In file.js I prompt the user some questions and then have a function handleThing() which just has a switch statement basically saying

> if x>1 then a = "hello world"; else a = "goodbye"

In test.js I want to invoke handleThing() and then test x. I first set x = 0 globally in test.js and I want to write a test like:

> describe("handleThing", function(){
>
> execute handleThing();
>
> it("should assign x", function(){
>
> expect(x).to.equal("goodbye")
>
> }}

Comment: Where is x defined? You don't show it anywhere here.

Comment: x is defined globally in the test.js

Comment: Then how do you expect handleThing to access it without passing it as a parameter?

Comment: handleThing can access variables defined globally; I just explicitly tried it to confirm

Comment: But why are you testing x if your handleThing code isn't trying to change it?

Comment: I have other functions later on which depends on this variable x. I just want to confirm that x is what I say it is. Unless I should just proceed with the understanding that x is that. I don't have much experience with testing but I assumed this first test was necessary

Comment: My point is that the content of your function doesn't change x like your test expects, it changes `a`.  That said, generally you should try to make functions without side effects and just test the output and parameters, not global values or internals.

Comment: file.js ```export function getX() { return x; } ```